# Modelica array of partial model

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

Let `A` be a partial model and `C`, `D` be models which extend `A`. Given a model

```
partial model X
  A a[3];
end X;
```

how can I instantiate X, e.g. something along the lines of

```
A X.a = {C,D,C};
```

**Update**: I tried 2 variants. One is

```
package P
  partial model A end A;
  model B extends A; end B;
  model C extends A; end C;
  partial model X
    A a[3];
  end X;
  model Y extends X(a={c,b,c});
    B b;
    C c;
  end Y;
end P;
```

which fails with the warning *"May only set inputs, parameters, and variables with default, but modified a."*. The other one is

```
package P
  partial model A end A;
  model B extends A; end B;
  model C extends A; end C;
  partial model X
    replaceable A a[3];
  end X;
  model Y extends X;
    redeclare A a={c,b,c};
    B b;
    C c;
  end Y;
end P;
```

which fails with the error *"Component a = {c,b,c}, but previously a = << Empty >>. The components are not identical."*

Note that it is possible to do the following.

```
package P
  partial model A end A;
  model B extends A; end B;
  model C extends A; end C;
  partial model X
    A a[3] = {a1,a2,a3};
    replaceable A a1,a2,a3;
  end X;
  model Y extends X;
    redeclare B a1;
    redeclare C a2;
    redeclare B a3;
  end Y;
end P;
```

But I want `P.X` to use a parametric array. Then again, the following idea to achieve this, does not work.

```
package P
  partial model A end A;
  model B extends A; end B;
  model C extends A; end C;
  partial model X
    parameter Integer N;
    replaceable A a[N] = fill(ai,N);
    A ai;
  end X;
  model Y extends X(N=3);
    redeclare A a[3] = {b,c,b};
    B b;
    C c;
  end Y;
end P;
```

Comment: Do you really need that `A` is `partial`? Your last example compiles if you remove the `partial` keyword before `model A end A;`. Declaring `A` as `partial` and then instancing it with `A a[...]` is a contradiction.

Comment: You're right, it is a contradiction. However, I would like A to be partial as it should act as a kind of abstract type which is not supposed to be instantiated. Do you have an idea how to do that in Modelica?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Is illegal to instantiate a partial model without extending it from a non-partial model. Something like this might work:

```
model Y
  extend X(a = {C, D, C});
end Y;
```

Then Y.a is what you want.

Comment: I tried 2 variants as described in my posting but both fail. Do you have an idea how to do it properly?

Comment: As far as I know the types of the elements of the array should be the same, subtype does not apply there. So I don't think you can assign components of different types (even via extends) to different array elements.

Comment: That would be very unfortunate. It is a basic element of object orientation. Are you aware of any "trick" how to achieve what I want, namely represent a set of elements of an base type?

Comment: From Modelica Spec Chapter 10, Arrays: "An array can be regarded as a collection of values, all of the same type".
In Modelica object orientation is used to encapsulate behavior and is not really that similar to normal object oriented programming languages where things are decided at runtime.

Comment: The question is: what do you want to model? Maybe it can be done some other way.

Comment: I motivated my question in a [new post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29715165/abstract-switch-in-modelica).

Answer (score 1):

[AFAIK](http://modref.xogeny.com/) a `partial` keyword means your model cannot be instantiated, so you'll probably have to `extend` X, too.