# Abstract switch in Modelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I would like to motivate a question I asked before about a [Modelica array of partial model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29424371/modelica-array-of-partial-model). Consider the following model of a switch between 2 controllers.

```
model Switch
  input Real u;
  input Integer sel;
  output Real y;
protected 
  Real x;
equation 
  if sel == 1 then
    y = 0.1 * (0 - u);
    der(x) = 0;
  else
    y = 0.1 * (0 - u) + 0.2 * x;
    der(x) = 0 - u;
  end if;
end Switch;
```

Let's ignore the fact that the PI controller may break when it is not selected for some time due to divergence of `x`. This can be fixed by resetting `x` when the PI controller is selected. However, this is not the point here.

I want to abstract this switch in 2 ways. Firstly, to switch among a parametric number of controllers. Secondly, to abstract controllers using partial models. Let `Ctrl` be the partial model of a controller.

```
partial model Ctrl
  input Real u;
  output Real y;
end Ctrl;
```

We can instantiate the two controllers embedded in the switch as follows.

```
model P extends Ctrl;
equation 
  y = 0.1 * (0 - u);
end P;

model PI extends Ctrl;
protected 
  Real x;
equation 
  y = 0.1 * (0 - u) + 0.2 * x;
  der(x) = 0 - u;
end PI;
```

The abstract version of the switch is supposed to be something like:

```
model Switch
  parameter Integer N(min=1);
  Ctrl c[N];
  input Real u;
  input Integer sel(min=1, max=N);
  output Real y;
equation 
  for i in 1:N loop
    c[i].u = u;
  end for;
  y = c[sel].y;
end Switch;
```

However, this model has some problems. Firstly, it is not clear how this model can be instantiated, e.g. with one `P` and one `PI` controller. Secondly, I get a warning which surprises me, namely: *The following input lacks a binding equation: `c[1].u`*

Is it possible to do express this abstract switch in Modelica in some way?

Comment: You can remove the for loop and use: Ctrl c[N](each u = u);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work with an array of models as you cannot bind it to different models via a modification. You need to specify all the controllers you have inside the GenericSwitch. You could generate the GenericSwitch and Switch model automatically if needed.

```
partial model Ctrl
  input Real u;
  output Real y;
end Ctrl;

model P 
  extends Ctrl;
equation 
  y = 0.1 * (0 - u);
end P;

model PI 
  extends Ctrl;
protected 
  Real x;
equation 
  y = 0.1 * (0 - u) + 0.2 * x;
  der(x) = 0 - u;
end PI;

model GenericSwitch
  replaceable model MyCtrl1 = Ctrl;
  replaceable model MyCtrl2 = Ctrl;
  MyCtrl1 c1(u = u);
  MyCtrl2 c2(u = u);
  input Real u;
  input Integer sel;
  output Real y;
equation 
  y = if sel == 1 then c1.y else c2.y;
end GenericSwitch;

model Switch = GenericSwitch(
  redeclare model MyCtrl1 = P, 
  redeclare model MyCtrl2 = PI);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess it should work with something like:

```
model GenericSwitch
  parameter Integer N(min=1);
  replaceable model MyCtlr = Ctrl constrainedby Ctrl;
  MyCtlr c[N](each u = u);
  input Real u;
  input Integer sel(min=1, max=N);
  output Real y;
equation 
  y = c[sel].y;
end GenericSwitch;

model PSwitch = GenericSwitch(redeclare model MyCtrl = P);
model PISwitch = GenericSwitch(redeclare model MyCtrl = PI);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but the 3rd line of your model has a syntax error. Besides, the array c would be an array of P controllers or PI controllers but mixing them would not be supported by your modeling.

Comment: I corrected the error. Sorry about that, I didn't check the code with any tool. As far as I know you cannot have an array with elements of different types. The only way you could do this is how you did it in the first model, and put all the equations in one model and select them based on ifs.

Comment: Why do you need an array of controllers?

Comment: There is a small typo: MyCtlr -> MyCtrl. I would have corrected it but an edit requires 6 characters from being different compared to the original post. One reason for an array of controllers is switched control where each controller is optimized for a different operating point.